# Curly brace in Coq generics

Tags: coq

The following code gives an error:

```
Inductive mylist {A : Set} : Set :=
| mylist_Nil
| mylist_Cons : A -> mylist A -> mylist A.
```

The error is "mylist A" of type "Set" cannot be applied to the term "A" : "Set".
If I change "{A:Set}" to (A:Set) then it works fine.

What does the curly braces mean?  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Usually, arguments are declared using parentheses.  Curly braces are used for *implicit* arguments.  Implicit arguments are not passed to functions and type declarations like usual ones; instead, the Coq type-checker tries to figure out what they should be from the context.

You can force a constant to take all arguments explicitly with an `@` sign, like this: `@mylist A`.

For generic types like `mylist`, there isn't enough context for Coq to infer what the `A` parameter should be, so it is usually better to declare those parameters explicitly, with parentheses.

The [Coq user manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/gallina-extensions.html#declaration-of-implicit-arguments) has more information on implicit arguments.